# PHP database selection mysql query .

Tags: php, mysql

How to get values for a given input by user from a database using php and mysql ?

```
function getStudent($id){

global $connection;
$query="select * Student where id={$id}";

$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result){

    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){

            echo "Name : ".$row["name"]."<br> Age : ".$row["age"] ;
    }

}

return $result; 

}
```

Please  find and fix the error

Comment: you are mixing mysql_* and mysqli. Please use mysqli as mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: You do not get any error while you try execute this code? I would try 
$query="select * Student where id=".$id;
Also try to use mysqli not mysql.

Comment: `Please find and fix the error` -- you haven't said what error you are encountering.

Comment: Please remove "global" It's horrible. And use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function getStudent($id){

global $connection;
$query = "select * from Student where id='".$id."'"; //use single quotes.
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //use mysql_fetch_array for retrieving data
       echo "Name : ".$row["name"]."<br> Age : ".$row["age"] ;
}

return $result; 
}
```

Comment: @Terance Wijesuriya try this and let me know :)

Comment: @TeranceWijesuriya accept & upvote my answer if it is working for u :)

Answer (score 2):

Please add 'From' in your query
`$query="select * from Student where id='".$id."'";`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function getStudent($id){

global $connection;
$query="select * from Student where id={$id}";

$result=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            $res[] array("Name"=>$row["name"], "Age"=>$row["age"] ;
    }
return $res; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the query you are writing

```
$query="select * Student where id={$id}";
```

It should be:

```
$query="select * from Student where id='".$id."'";
```

When you are mapping the database columns see that you are mapping it to the correct columns I,e Columns name should be same both in backend and front end.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. If you want to return whole result than return the result of fetch_assoc(). Like

```
if($result){
   while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
         $data[] .= $row;
    }
}
```

return this $data variable.